# PHP fseek with remote videos or alternative

Tags: php, linux, html, video, fseek

i am trying to make mp4 videos seek-able

the video is located on different server then the PHP file

regarding headers it send all correct info

but the problem is that fseek does not support remote video

i tried to use stream_get_contents instead

```
     stream_get_contents($fp, $start);
     fseek($fp, $start);
```

the video it self already converted and ready to stream

any idea how can that be done ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to start reading the content of `$fp` from a [different offset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php) you should use the 3rd parameter of the function:

```
string stream_get_contents ( resource $handle [, int $maxlength = -1 [, int $offset = -1 ]] )
```

In your case:

```
stream_get_contents($fp, -1, $start);
```

(in your original code you set the second parameter to $start, which is wrong).

> Keep in mind that not all streaming support offset, so it might not work.